# autostart website after web deploy

Tags: iis, iis-8, msdeploy, webdeploy, iis-8.5

I have a IIS website with multiple application connected to the same app pool and I deploy regularly some of those website through web deploy with the msdeploy tool. One of this app is set to autostart with the `serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"` and a matching `serviceAutoStartProvider`.

It works well when I restart the whole app pool but the autostart is not triggered when I web deploy the website

Is there any way to tell IIS to "restart" fully the website after the deploy and not wait for the first request to it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a post sync command:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -preSync:runCommand="net stop w3svc" -source:webserver60 -dest:auto,computername=serverA -verbose -postSync:runCommand="appcmd start site /site.name: contoso"
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Isn't it a bit brutal to stop all the IIS service ? I have other app on the IIS that should not be affected.

Comment: This won't stop the IIS service just the site.